# What is the best way to specify whether InstallPrivileges is limited or elevated at the command line in WIX?

Tags: wix, uac, limited-user

I want to create an MSI in WiX such that it can take a command line parameter to indicate whether it is a per-machine or per-user installation and consequently whether to raise a UAC dialog.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to test in Vista yet, but what works in XP for limited user per user install and admin user per machine install is the following:

msiexec /i myinstaller.msi ALLUSERS="" INSTALLDIR="C:\Documents and Settings[Username]\Local Settings\Application Data\My COmpany\My Program"

The INSTALLDIR can be anything that a limited user can write to.  The above is the directory Google Chrome uses.  Found from the following link that the ALLUSERS property can actually be blank which is distint from 1 or 2 and that correctly sets the ProgramDir and Desktop locations

http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/archive/2007/11/18/6385121.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This is the link for per-machine/per-user from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371865(VS.85).aspx).

so to change the values from the command line parameter, you'll need something like so:

msiexec /i myinstaller.msi ALLUSERS=[1|2]

Also, have a look at this [link](http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg07066.html) from wix-users

Answer (score 1):

The UAC dialog is controlled by a bit in the SummaryInformation stream. That, unfortunately, means it cannot be controlled at "run time" (install/repair/uninstall).  You have to build different MSI files to truly change the UAC prompt.